# facet in facet by specific value, and color and organize by group

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I want to add for this code:
Each strip.background will be colored by "Group" column and organize the facet by the groups.
In addition, split each graph to two graphs one above the other. Upper graph for lipid "GD1a" which with thousand scale on the y axis. Bottom graph for the rest of the lipids, with hundreds scales on the y axis.

Thanks

```
dat <- gather(dat, key="lipid", value="measurement", Total.GD1a:Total.GM3)
pdf("Lipidomics_graphs_per_patient.pdf", width=14, height=12)
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=Brain.region, y=measurement)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=lipid)) +
  facet_wrap(~Sample.Name) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
dev.off()
```

a little example from my data:

```
  Sample.Name Group   Brain.region          lipid      measurement
   <chr>       <chr>   <chr>                 <chr>            <dbl>
 1 P54/99      PD-GBA  Cingulate gyrus       Total.GD1a    3570.   
 2 P25/13      PD-GBA  Cingulate gyrus       Total.GM1      138.   
 3 P54/11      IPD     Cingulate gyrus       Total.GM1      188.   
 4 P23/98      PD-GBA  Striatum              Total.GM3        0.990
 5 P54/11      IPD     Occipital cortex      Total.GM3        3.32 
 6 P43/13      control Striatum              Total.GM1       77.9  
 7 P64/11      control Occipital cortex      Total.GD1a    2632.   
 8 P21/13      IPD     Middle temporal gyrus Total.GD2       76.5  
 9 P40/00      PD-GBA  Striatum              Total.GM1      102.   
10 P67/10      control Occipital cortex      Total.GM1      142.   
11 P6/08       IPD     Occipital cortex      Total.GM2        9.56 
12 P36/01      PD-GBA  Occipital cortex      Total.GM1      110.   
13 P25/01      PD-GBA  Cingulate gyrus       Total.GD2      174.   
14 P23/98      PD-GBA  Middle temporal gyrus Total.GM3        1.94 
15 P54/13      PD-GBA  Cingulate gyrus       Total.GD2      112.  

set.seed(1234)
dat_example <- dat %>% sample_n(15, replace = FALSE)
dput(dat_example)

structure(list(Sample.Name = c("C04/97", "P67/12", "P80/07", 
"P50/03", "P79/10", "P61/15", "P64/11", "P68/06", "P73/04", "P29/12", 
"P48/15", "P6/08", "P25/98", "59/94", "C04/97"), Group = c("control", 
"PD-GBA", "IPD", "IPD", "IPD", "IPD", "control", "PD-GBA", "PD-GBA", 
"control", "control", "IPD", "PD-GBA", "PD-GBA", "control"), 
    Brain.region = c("Occipital cortex", "Cingulate gyrus", "Cingulate gyrus", 
    "Occipital cortex", "Middle temporal gyrus", "Striatum", 
    "Striatum", "Striatum", "Occipital cortex", "Middle temporal gyrus", 
    "Striatum", "Occipital cortex", "Middle temporal gyrus", 
    "Striatum", "Middle temporal gyrus"), lipid = c("Total.GM3", 
    "Total.GD2", "Total.GD2", "Total.GD2", "Total.GD2", "Total.GD2", 
    "Total.GD2", "Total.GD1a", "Total.GD1a", "Total.GD2", "Total.GM2", 
    "Total.GM1", "Total.GM3", "Total.GM2", "Total.GD1a"), measurement = c(1.72785, 
    70.073, 97.289, 108.6805, 18.0735, 34.29075, 31.1428, 2589.50185, 
    2669.1055, 80.814, 3.24406869429729, 163.8335, 1.22105, 6.0281, 
    1273.784)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("Sample.Name", "Group", "Brain.region", 
"lipid", "measurement"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icLkI.png)

Comment: Please don't use pictures of data as a substitute of actual data. Consider getting a representative sample of your data and post the output with `dput(your_data)`.

Comment: thanks for your comment! I added a table, is it OK?

Comment: please post your data using `dput(dat)`

Comment: I'm not sure I'm doing it right .. I did well?

Answer (score 0):

To get the basic plot, you could use the following (assuming `df` is your example data):

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Brain.region, y = measurement)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = lipid)) +
  facet_grid(vars(ifelse(lipid == "Total.GD1a", "GD1a", "Others")), 
             vars(Group),
             scales = "free_y") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
g
```

[image]

Now we don't have the colours for the strips yet, which is a bit of a pain to do. Here follows a gtable approach:

```
# Convert to gtable
gt <- ggplotGrob(g)

# Get top strips
tstrip <- which(grepl("strip-t", gt$layout$name))
colours <- c("red", "green", "blue")

# Replace strip background fill
# Correct subset found through trial and error
for (i in seq_along(tstrip)) {
  gt$grobs[[tstrip[i]]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[1]]$gp$fill <- colours[i]
}

# Plot
library(grid)
grid.newpage(); grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you!
but I need different graph for each Sample.Name and just the color by the group.

Comment: That is, for this example I want to get 15 graphs for 15 samples, each graph split to two graphs for GDa1 and others. (In the total, I have above 60 samples). In addition, I need to distinguish each sample by its respective group.